# Error for Group Search - Unsupported Query

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to find the group ID from the display name of the group, using the Microsoft Graph API.

My code:

```
group = 'Test'
uri5 = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$count=true&$filter=displayName eq ' + group

payload5 = {'Authorization':token,'Host':'graph.microsoft.com','ConsistencyLevel':'eventual'}

https = urllib3.PoolManager()
response5 = http.request('GET', uri5, headers=payload5)

mydict5 = eval(response5.data)
groupID = f"{mydict5['id']}"
```

I receive the error:

```
{'error': {'code': 'Request_UnsupportedQuery', 'message': 'Unsupported Query.'}
```

I am not sure what I am missing here. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I have created one Azure AD group named **`Test`** like below:

[image]

I created one Azure AD application and granted **permissions** as below:

[image]

Now, I ran the **same code** as you from previous question and got the **`token`** successfully as below:

```py
import urllib3
uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token"
payload= {

    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Host': 'login.microsoftonline.com',
    'client_id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
    'client_secret': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
 }
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
response = http.request('POST', uri, payload)
my_dict = eval(response.data)
token = f"{my_dict['token_type']} {my_dict['access_token']}"
print(token)
```

**Output:**

[image]

When I ran the **same code** to get the group, I got the **same error** as below:

```py
group = 'Test'
uri5 = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$count=true&$filter=displayName eq ' + group

payload5 = {'Authorization':token,'Host':'graph.microsoft.com','ConsistencyLevel':'eventual'}
https = urllib3.PoolManager()
response5 = http.request('GET', uri5, headers=payload5)
print(response5.data)

#mydict5 = eval(response5.data)
#groupID = f"{mydict5['id']}"
```

**Output:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, try to modify your code like below:

```py
group = "'Test'"
uri5 = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$count=true&$filter=displayName eq ' + group

payload5 = {'Authorization':token,'Host':'graph.microsoft.com','ConsistencyLevel':'eventual'}
https = urllib3.PoolManager()
response5 = http.request('GET', uri5, headers=payload5)
print(response5.data)

#mydict5 = eval(response5.data)
#groupID = f"{mydict5['id']}"
```

When I ran the above modified code, I got the **response** with **`groupID`** successfully like below:

[image]

**UPDATE**

I agree with *user2250152*, and got **`groupID`** running same code as below:

```py
group = "'Test'"
uri5 = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$count=true&$filter=displayName eq ' + group

payload5 = {'Authorization':token,'Host':'graph.microsoft.com','ConsistencyLevel':'eventual'}
https = urllib3.PoolManager()
response5 = http.request('GET', uri5, headers=payload5)
#print(response5.data)

mydict5 = json.loads(response5.data)
groupID = f"{mydict5['value'][0]['id']}"
print(groupID)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: When I try to run the mydict5 command though to add the ID to a dictionary, I receive an error.
`>>> mydict5 = eval(response5.data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'null' is not defined`

Comment: Glad to know you resolved it! Still adding output image for future reference by updating the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's more python issue caused by wrong formatting.

```
group = 'Test'
uri5 = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$count=true&$filter=displayName eq ' + group
```

When you try to print `uri5` the result is

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$count=true&$filter=displayName eq Test
```

As you can see single quotes are missing after `eq` operator. You can either wrap it in doubles quotes

```
group = "'Test'"
uri5 = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$count=true&$filter=displayName eq ' + group
```

or use formatting string with F-Strings

```
group = 'Test'
uri5 = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$count=true&$filter=displayName eq \'{group}\''
```

Result:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$count=true&$filter=displayName eq 'Test'
```

The response data `response5.data` is json string. You can import json package and read the value like this

```
import json

group = 'Test'
uri5 = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$count=true&$filter=displayName eq \'{group}\''

payload5 = {'Authorization':token,'Host':'graph.microsoft.com','ConsistencyLevel':'eventual'}

https = urllib3.PoolManager()
response5 = http.request('GET', uri5, headers=payload5)

mydict5 = json.loads(response5.data)
groupID = f"{mydict5['value'][0]['id']}"
```

Comment: I receive the same error as I did with the other proposed solution. None of these allow me to store the ID into a dictionary.
`>>> mydict5 = eval(response5.data) Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   File "<string>", line 1, in <module> NameError: name 'null' is not defined`

Comment: you need to parse json to dictionary and read the corresponded value, check updated answer.